# Changing name of `id` column in SphinxSearch index

Tags: sphinx

I have created a SphinxSearch index which look like this:

```
+---------+-----------+
| Field   | Type      |
+---------+-----------+
| id      | bigint    |
| message | field     |
| created | timestamp |
+---------+-----------+
```

Is there a way to run the indexer to change the name of the `id` column? I'm concerned about having multiple indexes all with a column called `id`. I would prefer to name it `message_id` or something more descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Id is a fixed name. Its the unique document id.

Can duplicate it into a unique attribute if you want